# Elegant pattern for nullable types

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, c#-6.0, null-conditional-operator

I have the following construct:

```
MyType y = x.HasValue ? f(x) : null;
```

I am aware of a simple pattern that can be used if `f` was a member of `x`: `MyType y = x.?f();`

Is there a similar way to simplify the above code without changing the definition of `f`?

Comment: Make f return null when taken parameter is null. ;)

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Looks like the [*Maybe Monad*](https://github.com/phlik/Monads.net/blob/master/Monads.NET/Maybe.cs)

Comment: Your current code is clear. Do you really want to make it less understable to save a few characters? If yes, you can try extension method. Say, `int? i = null; int? = i.Call(f);` with extension method `static R Call<P>(this P? parameter, Func<P, R> func) { if (parameter.HasValue)  return func(parameter.Value); else return default(R); }`.

Comment: You could make an extension method for x that encapsulated this code, so you could call `x.IfNotNull(F)`, or something.

Comment: No, there is no similar way to simplify the code without changing the definition of F. Since F expects to be fed a non-null value, you must involve a ternary operator to avoid calling F when x is null.

Comment: I was looking for something more native to C# to avoid extension methods and anything else that would require adding more code. I guess there's no need for such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present (November 2015), no such mechanism exists in C#.

Options are:

1. Change `f` to return `null` when parameters are `null`
2. Make an extension method

---

```
static R Call<P>(this P? parameter, Func<P, R> func)
{
    if (parameter.HasValue)
        return func(parameter.Value);
    else
        return default(R);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is the null coalescing operator '??'

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx):

```
// Set y to the value of x if x is NOT null; otherwise
// if x == null, set y to -1
y = x ?? -1;
```

Assuming `f()` can handle `x` being `null` and will `return null` if not, but then you could just do `MyType y = f(x)`, which sounds like your best bet. Keep in mind, anything other than changing the function to handle x being null would require you to remember to do it on your own, as well as remember why, thus creating room to shoot your own foot and removing a layer of abstraction.

Also, doesn't `f(x)` take a nullable type and is therefore expecting one anyways?